# VM How to setup 2 NIC for FailOver IP (BridgeClient)

Tags: virtual-machines, failover, xenserver, nic, ovh

I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to setup correctly my new VM's NICs. The server have 2 NIC under Centos 6.8, both will need to be configured to their own (OVH) Failover IP address.

OVH the hosting company already explained how to configure the first NIC using a BridgeClient. I followed their tutorial (http://help.ovh.com/BridgeClient) and it's working flawlessly.

My eth0 configuration:

Contents of the file: `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
USERCTL=no
IPV6INIT=no
PEERDNS=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
IPADDR=IP.FAIL.OVER
GATEWAY=GATEWAY_VM
ARP=yes
HWADDR=MA:MAC:VI:RT:UEL:LE
```

Contents of the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0`

```
GATEWAY_VM dev eth0 default via GATEWAY_VM dev eth0
```

Contents of the file `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 213.186.33.99
```

`GATEWAY_VM` is my dom0's ip address ending with 254

So now I simply need to create another NIC for the second FailOver IP.

I tried to create and configure eth1 using the procedure above but it's not reaching anything. I cannot ping my server using the second IP.

I would simply need that both IPs reach my VM and that my VM use eth0 as the default internet connection and be able to listen and respond to request on eth1 (since the server will be use to mysql and apache I'm not sure if the response from eth1 request can be answered on eth0 or if it need to be answered from eth1. You guys probably know the solution).

I reached my hosting company their simply suggested to use ipaliasing but this solution is not suitable for me since I need to use a different Mac Address for eth0 and eth1.

Comment: Please define **failover ip**. What mechanisms are involved to let the clients know that your service is reachable on a different IP. Is your second IP on a different subnet?

Comment: Hi @Nils, failover ip is how OVH my provider call the ip address I have. It's an ip that can be moved from a physical server to another server in their datacenter so In case of a server maintenance I can switch the failover ip to my standby server so the website will stay available to the user (since the ip stay the same I don't have to worry about dns propagation). For more detail https://www.ovh.com/ca/en/dedicated-servers/ip_failover.xml So basically I need to configure 2 failover ip, eth0 for default route and eth1 for serving request from the second ip.